# Find all paths of length k

Tags: graphs, matrices

I have an adjacency matrix, call it `A`, representing a directed graph. I want to find all paths of length k. I know that `A^k` gives me the number of paths of length k between `i` and `j`, for each entry `(i, j)`. But I want to know the actual edges in these k-length paths.

What's the best way to find all k-length paths in my graph? I read somewhere that exhaustive search on the adjacency matrix is the best way—but if so, how exactly to go about this?

Comment: See also http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/19761/755 and http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/21381/755 for related problems (but not identical).

Comment: in https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/44281 a BFS search was suggested.

Comment: It depends on your expectation of a "non-exhaustive" method. Do you need a magical poly-logarithmic algorithm or an $O(nm)$ solution makes you happy?